# Qt: How can I add two different external library path?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to add two different external library path on Qt. So I put INCLUDEPATH and LIBS below to .pro file;

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/SiliconSoftware/Runtime5.4.0/include \
C:/Basler/pylon4/pylon/include

LIBS += -L"C:\SiliconSoftware\Runtime5.4.0\lib\visualc" \
-lclsersis \
-ldisplay_lib \
-lfglib5 \
-lgbelib \
-liolibrt \
-lsiso_auxport \
-lsiso_genicam

LIBS += -L"C:\Basler\pylon4\pylon\lib\Win32" \
-lPylonUsb_MD_VC100_TL \
-lPylonUtility_MD_VC100 \
-lPylon1394_MD_VC100_TL \
-lPylonBase_MD_VC100 \
-lPylonBootstrapper \
-lPylonCLSer_MD_VC100_TL \
-lPylonGigE_MD_VC100_TL \
-lPylonGUI_MD_VC100
```

But I got this error;

> C:\Users\GitekVision\Documents\Qt Projects\PylonSetUp\pylonsetup.h:4: error:          >C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pylon/PylonIncludes.h': No such file or >directory.

I tried to take libraries one by one, it works. But together not working.

Anyone knows how to use 2 different external library on Qt project?

Comment: Is this path `C:/Basler/pylon4/pylon/include/pylon/PylonIncludes.h`  correct on your computer, can you open that file if you put the path in explorer?
[Edit:] The error indicates that it is an compiler error, not linker error, so the issue is with INCLUDEPATH, it is not yet getting to the LIBS part

Comment: If you external libraries are in different folders you need to specifiy the full path

Comment: The include path certainly correct. I checked for it. And also when i enter the libraries in the header file it recognises the path. Is it correct to write LIBS path and libraries separeted like above or should I combine them in one LIBS code.

Comment: @ErdincTurk You can use either one of the 2 options, what you have is just as correct as adding it into one `LIBS` variable.